# How can I solve a chessboard puzzle of size 100X100?

Tags: pattern-recognition, chessboard

I have 800 rooks. How can I place them on a chessboard ?

Comment: Are you asking for the number of ways this can be done?

Comment: Do rectangles with slanted (but still perpendicular) sides count as rectangles?

Comment: Did you try it on the normal 8×8 chessboard? What did you get? Were you able to do it?

Comment: @Firexsecred Are you going to post an answer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's from an ongoing contest https://www.codechef.com/MAY19A/problems/ADAROKS2